# Where can I read the complete ''Sri Ramakrishna: The Great Master'' (English) by Swami Saradananda?

Tags: translation-request, ramakrishna

I would want to read the complete ''Sri Ramakrishna: The Great Master'' translated from Bengali (Sri Ramakrishna Leela Prasanga written by Swami Saradananda) in English (by Swami Jagadananda). Could anyone help me?

Comment: check this link: http://estudantedavedanta.net/Sri%20Ramakrishna%20-%20The%20Great%20Master%20by%20Swami%20Saradananda%20[1080%20Pages,%20A%20Detailed%20Biography]%20%281%29_r.pdf

Comment: Are you sure? That's what you need.

Comment: @CR241 Yeah absolutely

Comment: Please search before you ask. Some books can be easily found through simple Google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For complete **''Sri Ramakrishna: The Great Master''** by Swami Saradananda translated PDF:

Check this below Link: http://estudantedavedanta.net/Sri%20Ramakrishna%20-%20The%20Great%20Master%20by%20Swami%20Saradananda%20[1080%20Pages,%20A%20Detailed%20Biography]%20%281%29_r.pdf

Note: Based on comments I posted this link in answer, I hope you enjoy to read this book.